How to write cookies via websocket in Express?
I'm trying to figure out how to write cookies via sockets in a shared session setup, but I'm unable to figure it out. I can edit the session and all, but that's it. I'm showing the setup I've made to share session between Express and socket.io:
// server.ts
import express, {ErrorRequestHandler} from 'express';
import session from 'express-session';
import {Server} from 'socket.io';
import sharedSession from 'express-socket.io-session';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: corsOptions, // Setting origin and credentials to true in variable
});

// Setting up the middleware
const sessionMiddleware = session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET!,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: cookieOptions, // Used on several places
});
const cookieMiddleware = cookieParser(process.env.SESSION_SECRET)
app.use(cookieMiddleware);

app.use(sessionMiddleware);
io.use(sharedSession(sessionMiddleware, cookieMiddleware, { autoSave: true }));

From here, everything seems to work. I can access to cookies and session from websocket, and edit session info. But visibly, changing socket.handshake.session.cookie doesn't do anything.
Note that what I exactly want to do is to change maxAge and/or expires to a year upon login if the user wants to be remembered. By default, the cookie lasts for the session, and for now, the only way I found to do it is to do a RESTful request after the login was successful to change the session cookie's expiration to a year.
Is there a way to do so via socket, or it's actually the only way to do so?
